# Parsing WebLogic Cluster Using RegEx

Tags: regex, servicenow

I haver the below file that I need to parse out the hostname and port from each cluster.

End result should look like this for example:

Host = server1
Port = 40002

But I also need the ones with the FQDN

Host = server1.unix.domain.com
Port = 40002

I don't know enough about regex to accomplish this.

```
WebLogicCluster SERVER1:40002,SERVER2:40002
WebLogicCluster SERVER1:40002,SERVER3:40002
WebLogicCluster SERVER1:40002,SERVER4:40002
WebLogicCluster SERVER1:8003,SERVER5.unix.domain.com:8003
WebLogicCluster SERVER1.unix.domain.com:8007,SERVER6.unix.domain.com:8007
WebLogicCluster SERVER1.unix.domain.com:8011,SERVER7.unix.domain.com:8011
WebLogicCluster SERVER1.unix.domain.com:8011,SERVER8.unix.domain.com:8011
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
/[, ][^:]+:\d+/g
```

Im not sure if that's what you want:

```js
const data = `WebLogicCluster SERVER1:40002,SERVER2:40002
WebLogicCluster SERVER1:40002,SERVER3:40002
WebLogicCluster SERVER1:40002,SERVER4:40002
WebLogicCluster SERVER1:8003,SERVER5.unix.domain.com:8003
WebLogicCluster SERVER1.unix.domain.com:8007,SERVER6.unix.domain.com:8007
WebLogicCluster SERVER1.unix.domain.com:8011,SERVER7.unix.domain.com:8011
WebLogicCluster SERVER1.unix.domain.com:8011,SERVER8.unix.domain.com:8011`

const parse = data => {
  const regex = /(?: |,)(.*?):(\d*)/g, result = []
  let temp
  while (temp = regex.exec(data)){
    result.push({name: temp[1], port: temp[2]})
  }
  return result
}

console.log(parse(data))
```

Comment: I can get the first part without the /g flag, how can I get this to do the same after the comma. I have a feeling I am going to need to do this in two steps

Comment: but you are using my regex ? `/(?: |,)(.*?):(\d*)/g` ?" If so first match will be before comma and second after

Comment: Yes, true regex it works just like that. :) However, I am developing in a platform called ServiceNow, which has a different regex engine which does not use the /g flag.

Comment: hadn't you `js` tag at this question?

Comment: I did, then removed the tag since this wasn't regular JS. So my thinking with this would be to pass over this once with everything before the comma, then again with everything after the comma, then i can merge the two.

Comment: @BrandonWilson try this /[, ][^:]+:\d+/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136493/discussion-between-brandon-wilson-and-maciej-kozieja).

Comment: I used ,([^:]+):(\d+) to get the second set, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try this one:
`\W+([^:\s]+):(\d+)`
to break it down:

`\W+` should catch the space/comma before the server adress or any other non word character

`([^:\s]+)` will give you the server address

`(\d+)` is the port

Comment: I think we are on the correct path here, but when I use it it is only returning the first set before the comma

Comment: Looks like this application I am writing in doesn't support /g identifier

Comment: Since I can't use /g I may need to do this in two steps and merge my results. Next question would be how would I do this with the server and port after the comma?

Comment: split lines on commas and apply the regex to each item? sorry, i don't actually know much js, i just know regex

Comment: You can use `/g` take a look at my answer you just execute it not with `.match()` but with `.exec()`

Comment: ServiceNow isn't true JS so I can't use JS to modify the string. I have to rely on regex only. I can however split this up into two steps, one that parses before the comma, then the other after comma